# Excel: two workbooks have the same structure, but one has the size 12 of the other

Tags: excel, windows, file, memory, filesize

So I have two workbooks and they both have the same number of worksheets and almost same amount of cells with data, but the second weights 12 times more.. What might be the reason behind this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely cause is excess used range. Check the last used cell on each worksheet using Control End (but note this only shows the last visible used cell)

Then delete all rows and columns in the excess used range (but note that this may impact any formulas referencing beyond the last data cell)

Comment: While @QHarr is certainly correct that there are many possibilities my experience matches yours: most of the time it is all about (seemingly) unused excess ranges.

Comment: I tried Ctrl+End on the first worksheet and it gets me into column P and row 100 000 for no obvious reason - the cell in question is empty. Also I tried to copy the first workbook and use my macro on it and it turned the second workbook in the same heavy weight thing, even though it didn't edit the first worksheet, only cleared it: `.Range("A2:AO100000").Clear`. The same was done with the first workbook, but that didn't ruin it though...

Answer (score 1):

The reasons for this can be many and varied. A community question kind a thing.

Excel can carry lots of metadata around with it.

- File [crashes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/930253/the-file-size-of-an-excel-workbook-may-unexpectedly-increase-exponenti) can cause problems and increases in size
- Some one rebuilding something but not using an existing cache......
- Checking where last used cell is (Ctrl+End on each worksheet) - corrupt file can alter this by introducing erroneous data into fields.
- Checking if workbook is saved with sharing turned on (increases size)
- Apparently [sorting and inadvertently applying conditional
  formatting](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other-mso_2007/why-did-my-excel-file-suddenly-balloon-in-size/4ed21955-dadb-481c-b976-31430df4a14c?auth=1) to a wider range can increase file size.

**Tools that can help:**

Look at:

1) [workbook optimizer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=38793) for example.

2) Windows [spreadsheet compare](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Basic-tasks-in-Spreadsheet-Compare-f2b20af8-a6d3-4780-8011-f15b3229f5d8)

Another option:

Convert files to `.xlsb` (if allowed). This will compress files.

Some further options listed [here](https://excellenttips.wordpress.com/2012/09/19/how-to-troubleshoot-excel-file-size/):

- Delete Pivot Table Saved Data
- Remove Unnecessary Formatting
- Search for corrupt data and attempt to fix